# Проблема со связью

Tags: php, apache, сеть

Суть проблемы вот в чем:

Есть приложение на web-сервере, и есть сервер Oracle на другом компьютере в той же локальной сети. До недавнего времени все работало хорошо, а затем приложение начало падать с ошибкой: **The site is currently not available due to technical problems. Please try again later. Thank you for your understanding.**(приложение на Drupal) Интернет на web-сервере вроде бы работает, но иногда его локальный IP адрес не пингуется с других хостов, хотя сам он адреса этих же хостов замечательно пингует.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело? Могло ли это случиться из-за вируса?

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело может быть в кабеле или разъеме web-сервера (так как сервер Oracle доступен другим хостам)  но вот как проверить это удаленно не знаю. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ это сделать?

Comment: Какая операционная система? Когда сервер перестает пинговаться, попробуйте перезагрузить свитч/модем/маршрутизатор, который подключает сервер к сети. Если не помогло - сам сервер. Напишите, дает это эффект или нет.

Comment: Вообще сервер с DHCP на Windows Server 2008.Вроде бы ошибка исправлена, изменением ip-адреса web-сервера. Судя по всему адрес этого сервера каким-то образом был еще у одного устройства в сети. Как это могло произойти -неизвестно, тем более, что адрес сервера был зарезервирован и не мог быть присвоен по DHCP. Скорее всего кто-то его прописал вручную.